# vba in Excel is showing "can't find project or library" but with a local VARIABLE

Tags: excel, vba

My code is working in some computers and some other show the message "can't find project or library" here is the code that gives the problem:

```
sub doMyThings()
   myText = "Helo everyone"
   msgbox myText
End sub
```

As I said, in some computers I get de message "can't find project or library" and the compiler say that the probrel is myText variable... why?!

I solve the problem declarating the variable like this:

```
sub doMyThings()
   Dim myText as variant
   myText = "Helo everyone"
   msgbox myText
End sub
```

But the thing is that I have tons of code... That is a lot of job to find each variable and declare it to solve the problem :(

Any suggetstions?

Comment: While the above is correct, undeclared variables do not cause this issue, even though the IDE highlights them as such. [Missing references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32790396/11683) do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you GSerg,

This is the same idea I had. Now I saw another problem with the STRING functions.

In my pc they are running well like this:

```
sub myHappySub()
 myString = "hello everyone"
 msgbox left(myString,5)
end Sub
```

But in these other computers I need to write de DIM for the variable and the STRING for the left function like this:

```
sub myHappySub()
 DIM myString as variant
 myString = "hello everyone"
 msgbox strings.left(myString,5)
end Sub
```

Any idea what is going on in these other pc's?

Comment: Hi guys, I solve part of the problem by activacting the `OPTION EXPLICIT`, it looks like office 2010 or some 2016 has the `OPTION IMPLICIT` automaticaly activated, well... the `OPTION EXPLICIT` help me find all the variables to DIM them.

About the second problem, i need to add `VBA` to make all functions work like `VBA.left()` or `VBA.Chrw()`