# Creating a Macro that runs a query out of SQL and paste the data in Excel

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

So here's my dilemma I'm attempting to create a macro that runs a query out of sql that located in cell (Sheets("SQL").Range("G1")), and paste the data from that query into Sheets("Data").Range("B1").  I came up with the code below but I keep getting a compile error:  User-defined type not defined.  Please any insight on what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated.

```
    Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim StrSQL As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Cursor = xlWait

    Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

    StrSQL = " SET NOCOUNT ON "

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; DATA SOURCE=CFS-SERVERSQL;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=dmtrans;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute(Sheets("SQL").Range("G1"))

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets("Data").Range("B4:S50000").ClearContents
        Sheets(Data).Range("b4").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not set the reference for your ADODB objects.

You can either do this with early binding:

(Don't know the names exactly. I am using a german Excel)
Extras - References: Add the reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects vXXX with a click in the checkbox to your project.

Or you can do this via late binding. In this case you must declare your variable as `Object` and instantiate it via `CreateObject`. Please find a related question here: [Excel VBA: Late binding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26604111/5089204)

Comment: On the first sight your VBA looks OK, but I cannot test this here... Well, your question is only about the compiler error you got about "User defined type not defined". If my answer could solve this problem you should just try your code to see what happens. Than - if there are new problems / questions go and ask a new question (with a link to this if this helps...). If this could help you with the problem here, please vote up and or mark as accepted. Thx!